# 16 x 16 color block groups CSS + HTML

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem, i have a bunch of 16 x 16 blocks on a page with a fluid layout (1st image). The blocks also belong to a group, the groups are highlighted in the second image

What I would like to do is when i hover a block it shows that entire group somehow like a border (shown in image 3) the only constraint is that the blocks must stay the same color. - And yes the blocks in the same group are always next to each over.

[image: CSS-Help]

My first attempt was to have

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="color-block"></div>
    ...
    <div class="color-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="color-block"></div>
    ...
    <div class="color-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="color-block"></div>
    ...
    <div class="color-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `.group` was `display:inline-block` but this falls over when a group goes on to two lines (see image below)

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create irregular outlines with `:hover` using CSS. You'd have to do this using JavaScript to determine the positions of adjacent blocks and style them accordingly.